# Phone call state

Tags: android, telephony, phone-call

How do we know programmatically that the call I am making is received in the other side ?
I know that there are some phone states like IDLE, OFFHOOK and RINGING.
I want to be notified that the outgoing call I am making is received, is disconnected by the other side or is unattended by the other side.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I understand is that we cannot differentiate among the various states inside the OFFHOOK state, unless we have the internal package access.

If we have the internal package access then only we can know whether the call connected is actually received or missed or disconnected by the other side.

Comment: Hi can i know exactly for which internal package it refers to?

Answer (score 4):

Even though there is only three states available in android telephony manager,it is very easy to identify state for all situations in a phone call. 
So here we are receiving the 3 events from android such as RINGING,OFFHOOK and IDLE. And in order to get the waiting state of a call,we need to define our own states like **RINGING, OFFHOOK, IDLE, FIRST_CALL_RINGING, SECOND_CALL_RINGING**.
Please think in a way that we are receiving **events** from android and we will define our on call **states**.
Here is the method to get call states at *onReceive* method of broadcast-receiver without registering *phonestatelistener* and escaping from other complications. See the code.

```js
public class CallListening  extends BroadcastReceiver {
    static CustomPhoneStateListener customPhoneListener;
    private static final String TAG ="broadcast_intent";
    public static String incoming_number;
    private String current_state,previus_state,event;
    public static Boolean dialog= false;
    private Context context;
    private SharedPreferences sp,sp1;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor spEditor,spEditor1;
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //Log.d("intent_log", "Intent" + intent);
        dialog=true;
        this.context = context;
        event = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        incoming_number = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
        Log.d(TAG, "The received event : "+event+", incoming_number : " + incoming_number);
        previus_state = getCallState(context);
        current_state = "IDLE";
        if(incoming_number!=null){
            updateIncomingNumber(incoming_number,context);
        }else {
            incoming_number=getIncomingNumber(context);
        }
        switch (event) {
            case "RINGING":
                Log.d(TAG, "State : Ringing, incoming_number : " + incoming_number);
            if((previus_state.equals("IDLE")) || (previus_state.equals("FIRST_CALL_RINGING"))){
                    current_state ="FIRST_CALL_RINGING";
                }
                if((previus_state.equals("OFFHOOK"))||(previus_state.equals("SECOND_CALL_RINGING"))){
                    current_state = "SECOND_CALL_RINGING";
                }

                break;
            case "OFFHOOK":
                Log.d(TAG, "State : offhook, incoming_number : " + incoming_number);
                if((previus_state.equals("IDLE")) ||(previus_state.equals("FIRST_CALL_RINGING")) || previus_state.equals("OFFHOOK")){
                    current_state = "OFFHOOK";
                }
                if(previus_state.equals("SECOND_CALL_RINGING")){
                    current_state ="OFFHOOK";
                    startDialog(context);
                }
                break;
            case "IDLE":
                Log.d(TAG, "State : idle and  incoming_number : " + incoming_number);
                if((previus_state.equals("OFFHOOK")) || (previus_state.equals("SECOND_CALL_RINGING")) || (previus_state.equals("IDLE"))){
                    current_state="IDLE";
                }
                if(previus_state.equals("FIRST_CALL_RINGING")){
                    current_state = "IDLE";
                    startDialog(context);
                }
                updateIncomingNumber("no_number",context);
                Log.d(TAG,"stored incoming number flushed");
                break;
        }
        if(!current_state.equals(previus_state)){
            Log.d(TAG, "Updating  state from "+previus_state +" to "+current_state);
            updateCallState(current_state,context);

        }
    }
    public void startDialog(Context context) {
        Log.d(TAG,"Starting Dialog box");
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, NotifyHangup.class);
        intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(intent1);

    }
    public void updateCallState(String state,Context context){
        sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        spEditor = sp.edit();
        spEditor.putString("call_state", state);
        spEditor.commit();
        Log.d(TAG, "state updated");

    }
    public void updateIncomingNumber(String inc_num,Context context){
        sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        spEditor = sp.edit();
        spEditor.putString("inc_num", inc_num);
        spEditor.commit();
        Log.d(TAG, "incoming number updated");
    }
    public String getCallState(Context context){
        sp1 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        String st =sp1.getString("call_state", "IDLE");
        Log.d(TAG,"get previous state as :"+st);
        return st;
    }
    public String getIncomingNumber(Context context){
        sp1 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        String st =sp1.getString("inc_num", "no_num");
        Log.d(TAG,"get incoming number as :"+st);
        return st;
    }
}
```

Comment: one of the best code i found for call state... thank you

Comment: @ Arunbalan bro u have all state algorithm?. like active , disconnecting , disconnected

Answer (score 3):

You need a [PhoneStateListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html). With that is is possible to check the state of a phone call. You have to implement `onCallStateChanged`. This method is called every time the state of a phone call changes. Then you can do something like this:

```
 switch(state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                    Log.d("Call","Outgoing Call finished");
            break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                    Log.d("Call","Outgoing Call Starting");
            break;
        }
```

Comment: Is it not that OFFHOOK state means all of these dialing, call established and call hung ? how do I differentiate between these three. Where as in one link i saw that OFFHOOK state only means that call is connected. Please clarify.

Comment: with call connected I mean the other side has picked up phone. I also want to know if it is possible that the other side without picking up call if directly disconnects. then can i know about it?

Comment: Here you see the three states the call can have: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html

Answer (score 0):

you have to use broadcastreceiver with the following onReceive implementation to check for phonestate changes

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    this.context = context;
    final Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (intent.getAction().equals(
    TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED)){
        final String state = extras.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        if ("IDLE".equals(state)){
            //TODO
        }
        if ("OFFHOOK".equals(state)){
            //TODO
        }
        if ("RINGING".equals(state)){
            //TODO
        }
    }
}
```

And if you want to check for intermediate state, you can add e.g. state control in form of an integer ....